# VPN service/settings to allow local RDP

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop

I have a need for an on-site system to appear to be off-site and contacting on-site services (for testing).  I need multiple users to run these tests.

My first instinct is connect a VM system to a VPN service, except then we can't remote into the VM (by default).

Is there another solution (other than a physical system actually off-site)?

Is there a VPN service that allows (easily) allows for a configuration with RDP (or other services) excluded from the VPN while other traffic goes through the VPN?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does "to appear to be off-site" mean - traffic originating from an external, public IP?

Comment: Yes, basically.  We have services that behave differently depending on internal/external IP address, and troubleshooting is difficult when we can't properly "appear" as off-site.

Comment: I would use AWS EC2 instances (virtual machines) for this. Then they really and truly are sending traffic in from an external source: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/launch-windows-vm/